# UI not updating when viewmodel variable has changed jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, mutablestateof

My variable is defined as follows in my view model:

```
private val _overallStitchCount: MutableStateFlow<Int> = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val overallStitchCount: StateFlow<Int> = _overallStitchCount
```

If I then insert a project into my room database as follows:

```
fun addProject() {
        val id = projectData.value.size + 1

        val project = Project(
            uid = id,
            projectName = "Example Project $id"
        )

        projectRepo.insertProject(project)
        populateValues()
    }
```

and then in `populateValues()` I then do this:

```
fun populateValues() {
        try {
            _overallStitchCount.value = projectData.value.size
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
```

In my UI I then have the following to watch this variable:

```
Row {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.testTag(HomePageViewTags.valueOverallStitchCount),
                        text = "${viewModel.overallStitchCount.collectAsState().value}"
                    )
                }
```

However, for some reason this does not update the UI every time I then try to add a new project to my database. However, it then updates if I close and then reopen the app?

Thanks

Comment: In your viewmodel when you creating overallStitchCount can you try to make it a stateFlow not just cast it so you would write val overallStitchCount = _overallStitchCount.asStateFlow() and see if it works? Also i would highly suggest in your composable to make overallStitchCount as a variable in the beginning of the code and use collectAsStateWithLifecycle to optimize code for performance

Comment: MutableStates uses delegates internally in such a way that a composable subscribes to read changes and recomposes if new value is transmitted. `collectAsState().value` wouldn't subscribe to changes. You need to create a variable inside a composable by `val overallStitchCount by viewModel.overallStitchCount.collectAsState()` and setting `text = "#overallStitchCount"` to start recomposition on changes